# Terraform plan is not working because of error in validating provider credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am new here and also a new learner into terraform and AWS.

I have a question regarding the "terraform plan" command which does not work and gets me some kind of error about validating provider credentials. The OS I am using is Windows 10.

The error that is shown is:

> Error: configuring Terraform AWS Provider: error validating provider credentials: retrieving caller identity from STS: operation error STS: GetCallerIdentity, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: 2ecdd9ef-e5d6-4d69-9953-43b9d9482af8, api error InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
> │
> with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
> on main.tf line 10, in provider "aws":
> 10:     provider "aws" {

I have made the credentials firstly with command prompt using command:

```
SET VARIABLE="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
SET VARIABLE xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The terraform file has this content:

```
    terraform {
      required_providers {
        aws = {
          source  = "hashicorp/aws"
        }
      }
    }
     
    provider "aws" {
      region = "us-east-1"
    }
     
    resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_s3_bucket-123" {
        bucket = "my-s3-bucket-123"
    }
```

Because i got this error above i made the environment variables with power shell using this command:

```
$env:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$env:AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

I tried searching the internet for this kind of problem but did not find the same problem as i have it.

Comment: Everything you are working with is happening in the Power Shell or not? Have you maybe looked at this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/specifying-your-aws-credentials.html?

Comment: nope, i have not seen it.. I will have a look and let you know what i have done. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this [install AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html) on your computer and [setup aws config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html) for your account. Then you are good to go.

Like this -

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
```

You can also save for different users/accounts in one file -

```
[mac]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY

[jack]
aws_access_key_id=akjshfkjasdhfkjasdfhaksjd
aws_secret_access_key=adsjfh/adjfh/adfshjgasdjh
```

Best wishes.

Comment: i was able to solve my issue, i reinstalled the aws cli on my pc and than i used again the commands to set the local environment variables into my PC. Thank you for your answer